# Android Touch event with selected frame

Tags: android, touchscreen

I have a view animator that has a lot Button on it. I've  a OnTouchEvent for the view . codes works fine if I touch on space, but if I touch the button the code doesn't work. how can i fix it?

```
 final View frame = (View)findViewById(R.id.viewAnimator1);

    frame.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener() {

         public void onSwipeRight() {   

            viewAnimator.showPrevious();

             }                      
        public void onSwipeLeft() {

             viewAnimator.showNext();
                    }}
```

Comment: Did you set touchlistener for buttons?

Comment: nope i set it for vievanimator. but its not working on it, i think it's layer behind  on buttons.

Comment: You need to set touch listener for your buttons as well, otherwise they won't get touch event.

Comment: but view is have a lot of button, is it necessary?

Comment: yes, just try one button with setonclicklistener and see how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set on click listener for buttons, if  all of them makes the same work, you can extend button class and implement on click listener and use it instead of normal button